# mod_rewrite get variable returns Server errors 500

Tags: .htaccess, apache2, server-error

What i'm trying to do is make the link show like this

`http://api.example.com/users/useridhere/`

Whenever I try to put in the rewrite it gives me a Server Error.

Here is my current code

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ index.php?id=$1 [NC,L] 
DirectoryIndex index.php?id=Nobody`

If anybody could point out what I did wrong or post a fix I will appreciate that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, you're wanting to request and see this in the browser:
http://api.example.com/users/useridhere/

But display the contents of:
http://api.example.com/index.php?id=useridhere

If this is accurate, then maybe something like this in your [docroot]/.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^users/([\w-]+)$ index.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```